# Python unable to import anything that is in parallel directory, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, directory, system

So the structure of my directory is

```
src -- |
      a.py
      b.py
test -- |
      test.py
```

I have tried everything I could, I am not able to import a.py or b.py inside of test.py in any way

I am running Linux Mint 20.2

I am running Python 3.10.9

I am using venv virtual environment

This what I have tried:

1. Any time I use relative imports, I get this: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
2. Adding **init**.py to directories did not help
3. Adding to system path did not help and is not an option, other users will be using it on different OSes, including executable file and so on..
4. Running python -m is not an option as well
5. Moving all files to one folder to get rid of the structure is stupid and I am not doing that.

Nothing works, I am losing my head, importing a file from a folder in parallel should not be that complicated

I went through all of the similar questions on this page and nothing helped.

Comment: Where did you put the `__init__.py` file(s)?

Comment: Why using system path is not an option? You can do it on your `test.py` file independant of the os system. `from pathlib import Path; sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent)); from src import a`

Comment: @MattDMo tried all options, inside of src/ inside of test/ inside of top level folder and all of the possible variations in between